# How to filter out wmic process when searching for a process with a specific command line using wmic?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I tried to find an application by the name `myapp` directly from command prompt and from a batch script by running the following command:

```
D:\Files>wmic process where "commandline like '%myapp%'" get processid, commandline

CommandLine                                                                  ProcessId  
wmic  process where "commandline like '%myapp%'" get processid, commandline  10744     
myapp myarg1 myarg2 myarg3                                                   2423
```

I want to filter out the `wmic` process entry itself. I tried the following command:

```
D:\Files>wmic process where "commandline like '%myapp%' and commandline not like '%wmic%'" get processid, commandline

Node - XXXXXXXXXXX
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query
```

But it outputs an error as shown above.

I tried manually skipping the first line with `more +1` but it may happen that the order of output lines (processes) varies.

What could be done to remove the `wmic` process entry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify any one character within a range by surrounding it with square brackets `[]`.

Using the `java` example in your comments:

In a [`batch-file`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info) (double `%%` for the like statement)

```
@echo off
wmic process where "commandline like '%%[m]y-complex-application.jar%%'" get processid, commandline
```

in [`cmd`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cmd/info) (single `%` for like statement)

```
wmic process where "commandline like '%[m]y-complex-application.jar%'" get processid, commandline
```

**Why this works**

The `[]` specifies a range of characters that should or could be matched. For instance when doing `... like '%[abc]md%` it will match anything related to `amd`, `bmd` and `cmd`. The trick here is that the character within the `[]` is matched as a literal character and not with the `[]`. So in the event where we search `[m]yapp` it literally converts the string to find exactly the word `myapp`, however, your `wmic`s `like` statement does not contain this word at all, it contains the word `[m]yapp` and will not match it.

Then, some useless information. This trick also works for Linux' `grep` command as well as windows' `findstr`

example (`findstr`):

```
echo myapp | findstr /R "[m]yapp"
```

result:

[image]

example (Linux' `grep`):

```
ps -ef | grep "[t]nslsnr"
```

Result with and without `[]`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to run your particular command and return only the instance(s) you require, directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), is this:

```sh
wmic process where "commandline like '%myapp%' and not commandline like 'wmic%'" get processid, commandline
```

The idea of this mechanism is to exclude the wmic command line itself. It does that by asking for command lines which include anywhere the string `myapp` but do not include command lines which begin with the string `wmic`.

If this command is run within a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), the percent characters would require doubling, i.e.

```sh
wmic process where "commandline like '%%myapp%%' and not commandline like 'wmic%%'" get processid, commandline
```